# How to store update data on modal laravel

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, store

i have a update function to update data on table using modal for view . in my view this modal **can display data** but i stuck on my store procedure , if i die dump this data, its not showed , its my view , controller and route :

view :

```
<tbody>
                @php
                  $no=0;
                 @endphp
                 @foreach ($belum_dikerjakan as $i)
                <tr>
                  <td> {{++$no}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->users->nama_unit}}</td>
                  <td> {{$i->created_at}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->nama_pengadu}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->ipsrs->nama_bagian}} </td>
                  <td> {{$i->aduan}}</td>
                  <td><span class="badge bg-danger"> Belum Dikerjakan</span></td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-id="{{$i->id}}"
                    data-nama_unit="{{$i->users->nama_unit}}"
                    data-tgl_aduan="{{$i->created_at}}"
                    data-nama_pengadu="{{$i->nama_pengadu}}"
                    data-tujuan_aduan="{{$i->ipsrs->nama_bagian}}"
                    data-aduan="{{$i->aduan}}"
                    data-status="{{$i->status}}"
                    data-target="#modal-lg" >
                    Action
                  </button></td>
                </tr> 
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ubah Status Aduan</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            <form data-toggle="validator" action="{{route('update_aduan')}}" method="post">
              @csrf
              {{method_field('patch')}}
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="title">Nama Unit:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama_unit" id="nama_unit" class="form-control" data-error="Please enter title." required disabled/>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="title">Tanggal Aduan:</label>
                <textarea name="created_at" class="form-control" id="tgl_aduan" data-error="Please enter description." required disabled></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="title">Nama Pengadu:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="nama_unit" class="form-control" id="nama_pengadu" data-error="Please enter title." required disabled/>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Isi Aduan </label>
                    <textarea name="aduan" id="aduan" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Isi Aduan atau Keluhan ..."  required disabled></textarea>
                  </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Select Gender</label>  
                  <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">  
                       <option value="Belum Dikerjakan">Belum Dikerjakan</option>  
                       <option value="Sedang Dikerjakan">Sedang Dikerjakan</option>  
                  </select>  
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success crud-submit-edit">Submit</button>
              </div>
                </form>
```

and its my modal function

```
 <script>
$('#modal-lg').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var id           = button.data('id')
  var nama_unit    = button.data('nama_unit')
  var tgl_aduan    = button.data('tgl_aduan')
  var nama_pengadu = button.data('nama_pengadu')
  var tujuan_aduan = button.data('tujuan_aduan')
  var aduan        = button.data('aduan') 
  var status       = button.data('status') 
  var modal = $(this)

  modal.find('.modal-body #nama_unit').val(id);
  modal.find('.modal-body #nama_unit').val(nama_unit);
  modal.find('.modal-body #tgl_aduan').val(tgl_aduan);
  modal.find('.modal-body #nama_pengadu').val(nama_pengadu);
  modal.find('.modal-body #tujuan_aduan').val(tujuan_aduan);
  modal.find('.modal-body #aduan').val(aduan);
  modal.find('.modal-body #status').val(status);
})
</script>
```

its my controller

```
 public function update_aduan(Request $request)
{

 //$id = $request->id;
 //$aduan = Aduan::findOrFail($id);


 //$aduan->update($request->all());
 dd($request->all());


}
```

and its my die dump form this controller

```
    array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "fPAPkD358ulkxOJyhjS9mGIh93dDQOt0d7HbbVcN"
  "_method" => "patch"
  "status" => "Sedang Dikerjakan"
  "id" => null
]
```

i dont know if i remover this "//" on my all controller , if i submit this form its will going to 404

```
 Route::patch('/ubah_aduan', 'AdminController@update_aduan')->name('update_aduan');
```

someone can help ?

Comment: Use js or axios to send request data to server. Are you able to retrieve the data via jquery?

Comment: Didn't see you ajax code for posting the data to controller.

Comment: can some one references to me about this ? i think i just need a update function normally on laravel , i still need a ajax function on my controller ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you wrongly update the value on that id

```
 modal.find('.modal-body #nama_unit').val(id); //#nama_unit
 modal.find('.modal-body #nama_unit').val(nama_unit);
```